# Stop a border line from going under a floated image?

Tags: html, css

Hi have an image floated left and then paragraphs of text to the right of it. 
I want to have a greyline under the first paragraph but it spans the whole length of the parent div going under the floated image is there a way just to have the border line under the first paragraph?

http://jsfiddle.net/9GkZf/1/

HTML

```
 <div id = landpgcontent class="margintop20 ofh">
                            <div id="landpgtext" class="txtblack ofh">
                                <img id="landpgpic" src="Images/Shared/BlankImage.gif" alt="No Image" class="floatleft">
                                <p class="phdr bold greyline marginbot10">Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error</p>
                                <p>Totam rem aperiam, eaque quae ab illo quas lorem ipsum dolor sit.Totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo itatis et quasi architecto.</p>
                                <p></br> Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia oluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni itatis et quasi architecto quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut la xercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nis iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae conseq ntur magni itatis et quasi architecto quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut la xercitationem ullam.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

CSS

```
.floatleft {float: left;}
.floatright {float: right;}
.ofh{overflow: hidden;}

/*Content*/
img#landpgpic {width: 226px; height: 172px; margin-right: 20px;}
div#landpgtext {line-height: 1.3em;}
.greyline {border-bottom: 1px solid #b9b8b8;  display:block}​
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Overflow:hidden
```

on the paragraph .greyline

http://jsfiddle.net/9GkZf/4/

Answer (score 1):

Change the `display` style of `.greyline` to `inline-block` instead of `block`:

```
.greyline {border-bottom: 1px solid #b9b8b8;  display:inline-block}
```

See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZQ4Cb/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes - float the `.greyLine` paragraph left.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/9GkZf/3/

floated the .greyLine `<p>` left

Comment: Thanks for your input but if i do that then the next paragraph goes to the right of the floated one which is not what i want. Also if i minimize the window the text doesn't wrap around the image